# How can I open a new window in javafx with labels, textfields, etc.?

Tags: javafx

I'm quite new to javafx so apologies if my problem isn't that hard to solve.

I've been tasked with creating an interface which allows me to open multiple windows with text fields and labels in the new windows. I'm able to create buttons, labels, etc. on the main window but I can't seem to find a way to create these in the new window. I'm using grid pane for the interface.

I've attempted to use stack pane instead of grid pane for my code but since I'm quite new I'm unsure of how to do it properly. I instead tried to incorporate parts of the code in stack pane form but that didn't work either. attempting to use grid pane in another class also didn't work with the code not running at all.

Button and code to create a new window

```
Button btn = new Button("Make Booking");
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
        grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);

        Text actiontarget = new Text();
        grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent handle) {
                // Instantiate my new window
                MakeBooking mb = new MakeBooking();

                // Make a new Scene and Stage and link them all together
                Scene scene2 = new Scene(mb, 400, 300);
                Stage stage2 = new Stage();
                stage2.setTitle("Make a Booking");
                stage2.setScene(scene2);
                stage2.show();
            }
        });
```

Seperate class for MakeBooking Window

```
public class MakeBooking extends GridPane {
    public MakeBooking() {
        super();
        Button b = new Button("Test");
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText("Test");
        Label secondLabel = new Label("I'm a Label on new Window");

        GridPane grid2 = new GridPane();
        grid2.getChildren().add(secondLabel);

        this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Each time the code is run the windows are blank.

Thanks

Comment: the error is that you add the children to a newly created (inside MakeBooking constructor) gridpane without adding that to the MakeBooking. BTW, don't extend a class when you reach the same goal by configuring - layouts are meant to be _used_

Comment: I'm not too focused on making my current code function yet but rather find a way to edit new windows in my interface. Thanks anyway for the suggestions and I'll make some changes to my code.

Comment: actually, you too confused (as in not seeing the wood for the trees) and too quick in not to reading my comment thoroughly enough(the first part is what is important), so repeating: the button/label created in the constructor of MakeBooking are not added to the scenegraph - so why do expect them to appear anywhere on the screen ;)